# Can the numeral be styled In an InDesign footnote?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

When using InDesign's footnotes, it is possible to apply a paragraph style to the footnote from the **Type > Document Footnote Options …** dialogue. However this style doesn't effect the number that appears before the footnote (the parts shown in bold below)

**1** This is a footnote.

**2** Another footnote.

Is there any way of styling this part of the footnote?

*Note: I am not talking about the numeral that appears in the text to indicate the existence of a footnote.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paragraph styles *do* affect the numbers of the footnote text (or at least they should, I can't find a way for them not to).

If you want to style the number differently to the body of the footnote then you can use nested styles (or drop caps).

[image: InDesign footnote styling]

As you can see, I have applied a drop cap style to the first character of the paragraph style. The entire number of the footnote is treated as a single character though, regardless of the actual length of the string. So padding the footnote number with leading zeros, for example, will still style the entire number:

[image: InDesign footnote styling]